# Auction site in rails and working with bids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need some assistance in working with the bids on this app. When a user register they get to set their budget (which is an integer in the schema). Users are then able to create an item with a set price (which is also an integer in the schema for the items table).

Im trying to figure out when a user creates a bid on the item

A) How do I decrease the users current budget if the highest bidder, but if gets out bid, the money returns to their budget.

B) Increase the items "price" that has been set with the current highest bid.

heres a visual of the schema:

```
 create_table "bids", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "amount"
  end

  create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "price"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "budget"
  end
```

Bids controller:

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bid, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @bid = @item.bids.build
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @bid = @item.bids.new(bid_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bid.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Your item has been updated.'}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

    private
    def set_bid
      @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bid_params
      params[:bid][:user_id] = current_user.id

      params[:bid].permit(:amount, :user_id, :item_id)
    end
end
```

Items controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :user_signed_in?

  def index
    @item = Item.all
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

  end

  def edit
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @item.bids.build
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item successfully created.'
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new'}
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Your item has been updated.'}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit'}
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url }
    end
  end


  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def item_params
    params[:item][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params[:item].permit(:price, :user_id, :title, :bids_attributes => [:amount, :user_id, :item_id])
  end



end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a has_many :through relationship would fit well with this problem: a user can have many items through bids.

A) Each item page would have a form that updates the bid instance for that specific item. The form would have one field: the amount of the bid the user wishes to place.

In order to solve your first problem, each time the bid is updated you do the following:

1. Get the previous user id and add to its budget the old price that the bid had (this would return their money).
2. Update the bid instance with the current user_id and the newly placed bid (all this data would be passed through the form)
3. Decrease the new user's budget with the bid he placed.

B) I think that there is no need to update the item's price because keeping the item's original price is important. Thus,  instead of comparing a newly placed bid with the item's price, you would compare it with the last placed bid.

If you insist in updating the item's price, its rather easy. You would find the Item instance using your item_id stored in the bid instance and then you would simply update its price attribute with the newly placed bid.

**EDIT**

You can use the following code (not tested) as a starting point:

For your Item show action, you do the following:

```
def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @bid = Bid.find_by_item_id(@item.id)
  end
```

In your show view, you would have  a form like so:

```
<%= form_for @bid do |f| &>
  <%= f.label :bid_amount %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
  #etc....
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This form should route your request to the Bid controller update action which should have something like this:

```
def update
    @bid = Bids.find(params[:id])
    @item = Item.find(@bid.item_id)

    @old_user = User.find(@bid.user_id)
    @old_user.budget += @item.price + @bid.amount

    @new_user = User.find(params[:bid][:user_id])
    @bid.user_id = @new_user.id
    @bid.amount = params[:bid][:amount]
    @new_user.budget -= @item.price + @bid.amount

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bid.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Your item has been updated.'}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: how would I write the code for this? I add something like item.price + bid.amount in the bids controller but nothing happens.

Comment: I refactored the code a bit to my current code. I placed the update code after the save in the create method in the bids controller. But it's not changing the item price or reducing money from the budget.

Comment: Because im not using any update action for bids. Every time a user creates a bid its going through the create method in the bids controller.

Comment: Thats wrong. There is no need to create a bid every time; you just need to update it. Did you try using the code I gave you?

Comment: I did. It said could't find bids_path when I went to an items show page. If there is a single bid that keeps getting updated how do you keep track of past bids?

Comment: And also how would you update something that hasn't been created yet?